# how to make externalValue in requestBody working (OpenAPI)

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to put the requestBody in an external file like this :

[image: request body example]

but it seems that it doesn't work

the file is in the resource folder :

[image: resources]

The file is a classic JSON file. if someone know how to make this work please.

thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What result do you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: If you mean you don't see the `externalValue` example in Swagger UI, that's because Swagger UI [does not support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433) `externalValue` yet.

Comment: Did you find how to do it? Thanks.